# Como filtrar um objeto pelo nome da propriedade?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
obj = {
  "storySummaries": {
    "featuredStories": [],
    "trendingStories": [
      {
        "image": {
          "newsUrl": "...",
          "source": "...",
          "imgUrl": "..."
        },
        "entityNames": [
          "A",
          "B",
          "C"
        ]
      }, {
        "image": {
          "newsUrl": "...",
          "source": "...",
          "imgUrl": "..."
        },
        "entityNames": [
          "D",
          "E",
          "F"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "date": "4 de mar de 2019",
  "hideAllImages": false
}
```

E desejo construir um array com todos os campos de todos os **entityNames**.
Como faço para obter um array do tipo `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`?

Tentei o seguinte código mas achei ele muito "feio":

```
let hotTrendStories = JSON.parse(results)['storySummaries']['trendingStories'];
let entities = [];
hotTrendStories.forEach((story) => entities = entities.concat(story['entityNames']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma segunda implementação menor é possível com `Object.values()`

```
var obj = {
    storySummaries: {
        featuredStories: [],
        trendingStories: [
            {
                image: {
                    newsUrl: '...',
                    source: '...',
                    imgUrl: '...',
                },
                entityNames: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
            },
            {
                image: {
                    newsUrl: '...',
                    source: '...',
                    imgUrl: '...',
                },
                entityNames: ['D', 'E', 'F'],
            },
            {
                image: {
                    newsUrl: '...',
                    source: '...',
                    imgUrl: '...',
                },
                entityNames: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
            },
        ],
    },
    date: '4 de mar de 2019',
    hideAllImages: false,
}
const entityNames = Array.concat.apply([],Object.values(obj)[0].trendingStories.map(item => item.entityNames))
```

Comment: Ao meu ver esse `Object.values` só atrapalha, aumenta a quantidade de código e deixa mais complexo, não vejo motivo algum pra usar

Comment: Concordo com o aumento de complexidade, mas não vejo como ele pode atrapalhar, pois utilizando `Object.values()` vc tem um código mais legível e próximo do funcional.

Comment: Pelo contrário `Object.values` retorna um array com os valores do objeto, basicamente converte um objeto para array, então `Object.values(obj)[0]` é igual a `obj.storySummaries` porém o segundo é bem mais legível e simples, além de não depender da ordem das propriedades

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `map` que recebe uma função para iterar sobre o array, recebendo como parâmetro os elementos, basta retornar a propriedade desejada, como essa propriedade é um array é preciso concatenar

```js
const list = [{
  "image": {
    "newsUrl": "...",
    "source": "...",
    "imgUrl": "..."
  },
  "entityNames": ["A", "B", "C"]
}, {
  "image": {
    "newsUrl": "...",
    "source": "...",
    "imgUrl": "..."
  },
  "entityNames": ["D", "E", "F"]
}];

let entityNames = list.map(item => item.entityNames);

console.log(entityNames);

entityNames = [].concat.apply([], entityNames);

console.log(entityNames);
```

Comment: Solução simples e clara. Gostei muito desse interpretador na resposta. Onde posso aprender mais sobre ele?

Comment: Não sei dizer, da uma olhada no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com), mas eu uso com o `Ctrl + M`. Só uma observação, do lado da resposta tem um ✓, que serve para aceitar a resposta que melhor atendeu sua dúvida, mas também tem um ▲ que serve para pontuar positivamente, a primeira você deve escolher apenas uma resposta para dar, já a segunda pode dar a todas